# Java on OpenVMS?

Tags: java, eclipse, openvms, vms

We run batch files on our OpenVMS Alpha and Integrity servers. Up until now they have been written in COBOL.  As you can imagine there are many reasons why will not be able to maintain that process.

At the same time we have a team of developers that use Eclipse and know Java very well.  Is there away to use Eclipse with OpenVMS?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's because I don't keep up with COBOL, but I am not sure why you're convinced you have to abandon it.  I realize it's not the "in" thing, but if you already have a large code base I'd think at least twice before switching to another language.  If it's a lack of developers, I don't think you're going to run out that soon.

That said, googling Eclipse & OpenVMS gave this link:
  http://www.sdtimes.com/SearchResult/32973
So it looks like you can still get Eclipse for OpenVMS from [eCube](http://www.ecubesystems.com/index.html).  If I'm reading that article correctly, HP seems to want you to go the NetBeans directions.  Personally, I'm still using Emacs (and not currently doing any Java), so won't make a recommendation; I just wanted to point out that there are other ways to develop Java than Eclipse.

I didn't find Java for VMS on Sun's site (someone feel free to correct me if you find it), but it looks like you can get the JDK from HP/Compaq at:
  http://www.compaq.com/java/download/ovms/1.5.0/index.html

Edit:  I meant, but forgot to say:  Assuming you're using a JVM on the VMS side, you should be able to development with Eclipse on another platform, and copy the byte code to the Alphas.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking from experience, if you do decide to rewrite your batch processes in Java I'd suggest you use a third party batching framework like [Spring Batch](http://static.springframework.org/spring-batch/) instead of 'growing your own'.

Using a framework also constrains you to work within a standard and should provide non-functional requirements like re-runability, transactions and error handling.

We've (re)built a number of batch processes from various technologies to Java using a home-grown framework and I find we end up spending time on fixing/optimizing the framework rather than just focusing on the business logic.

Comment: Speaking from the same experience, I completely agree. Of course, experience isn't as useful if it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave Cobol yet - call [a-cobol-programmer-thinking-about-switching-to-the-modern-world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312499/a-cobol-programmer-thinking-about-switching-to-the-modern-world) and make a trade: you teach him Java, He maintains your legacy.

Answer (score 1):

Shell scripts and java usually aren't a great mix. You may want to consider installing a JVM on your VMS servers, and using one of the JVM-hosted languages that handle that case better- jython, jruby, or groovy might be candidates to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse relies on native Java extensions that do not appear to have been ported to OpenVMS.  Don't give up though.  Java runs on OpenVMS (at least 1.5 according to a Google search).

NetBeans has a Java only edition that *should* work on OpenVMS.  On the [NetBeans Download Page](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/) select the OS Independent Zip option for the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the batch files on your OpenVMS system?  If so, HP makes Java available for OpenVMS, not SUN; you will have to look at their site.  You can develop your java code on a windows/linux machine and test it on your VMS system; you must be aware of the native extensions that you cannot use on the VMS implementation of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking with some experience in this area, I suggest developing with Eclipse on your Windows/Linux/Mac desktop, and pushing the code out to OpenVMS for testing/deployment.  Eclipse won't run on OpenVMS because of some platform-specific components of its GUI.

Some caveats:

- Make sure that you are using the same version JVM on your desktop as on OpenVMS.
- The case insensitivity in OpenVMS can be a problem when using inherently case-sensitive Java .class files.  Package everything in a .jar and deploy it that way.
- The attributes on .jar files have to be set correctly or the OpenVMS JVM can't open them.  The following command should do the trick:
  `SET FILE *.jar /ATTR=(RFM:STMLF,RAT:CR)`
- HP provides both a "fast" JVM and a "classic" JVM.  Use the fast VM unless your memory needs are highly variable.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is rather old, but I was shocked nobody mentioned this book covering Java on OpenVMS.

https://www.theminimumyouneedtoknow.com/java_book.html

What really matters when using an x86 editor on OpenVMS source is your file transfer software. OpenVMS (and many other midrange ASCII based platforms) use  even though most PC developers say LineFeed Carriage Return, the data files typically store it in the other order.

You can read much more about that here:
https://www.logikalsolutions.com/wordpress/information-technology/most-text-editors-get-tabs-wrong/

Your file transfer software will need to perform text mode file transfer changing the line ending characters **OR** your editor needs to both use and respect the better systems line ending characters. I *thought* there was something in Eclipse (via plug-in) to handle this. Notepadqq claims to have something.

**Note this:** They use Eclipse for development, not just editing.

That means they are running and debugging in their own PC based Eclipse universe and that ain't how it's going to work on OpenVMS. They are going to need a terminal into the VMS system and it needs to be a **REAL VT-100** terminal emulator, not the worthless free stuff. You can read a little bit more about that here:

https://www.logikalsolutions.com/wordpress/information-technology/diamond-edt-keypad-support/

and here

https://www.logikalsolutions.com/wordpress/information-technology/xterm-and-vt-emulation/

Depending on how old your system is, you might have [Pathworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathworks) installed and running. Then a system manager can create a directory for each user that they can map as a network drive to the PC. This lets the PC user use the directory like any other network disk and it generally could be configured to handle the line ending issues with text files.

There is no way they can *develop* on OpenVMS using Eclipse. They can edit files then test on OpenVMS, but they cannot develop within the IDE which I suspect is what they really want to do.

The only GUI that ever existed for OpenVMS was [DECWindows](https://vmssoftware.com/products/decwindows-motif/). You had to run it on either a VAXStation or a DS model Alpha workstation. I never heard of Eclipse being ported to it. In the latest port of OpenVMS to x86 there is no GUI. It is a server only OS.

Yeah, I spent two decades on the platform and even wrote [this book](https://www.theminimumyouneedtoknow.com/app_book.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a version of `Eclipse` that supports `OpenVMS` called `NXTware Remote`. It has support for *Java* and *COBOL* languages as well as *Fortran*, *Basic* and *Pascal*.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit OpenVMS files using pretty much any editor, including Eclipse - just use Samba to make OpenVMS directories and files visible to desktops on the network. If you install Java for OpenVMS, then you've got folks using Eclipse, and compiling and running on OpenVMS.

As for ditching Cobol - why?  There's still a ton of companies running it, and it will certainly last for decades more.